# Make a photo or video with the camera and automatically find you via GPS

Tags: android, gps, android-camera

I want to make a button that when you press open the camera and you can take a photo and that automatically takes the coordinates of where you made that photo.
I would appreciate if you could give me the code because I have no idea.

Thanks.

PD: Sorry for my English but I´m not english.

Comment: We do not just give code when there has been no apparent attempt to do research or try something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirement is need to take photo with GPS Location Details. If yes means please refer the following link. It will help you.

[Getting location data for a taken photo in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359227/getting-location-data-for-a-taken-photo-in-android)